# How to filter file name in Nifi

Tags: hadoop, apache-nifi

I want to ingest data from email attachment to my HDFS path, for which i am using Nifi processor. There are multiples files are attached in attachment, i want a particular one. How to filter it in nifi?

Comment: Based on which logic, you wants to filter the filename?

Comment: I feel like you should rather be asking, how do you get the list of files... From that, you might be able to filter. Anyway, which processors are you using?

Answer (score 3):

If each of the attachment file is being as a separate FlowFile and you want to filter using filename then you could use `RouteOnAttribute` to filter the attachment files of interest and then connect it to `PutHDFS`.

For the above scenario, you can set the following property in `RouteOnAttribute`:

```
attachmentOfInterest : ${filename:equals("<interested_filename>")}
```

If you don't want to filter based on filename but based on something else, you can still follow this `RouteOnAttribute` approach but use different NiFi expression language instead of `filename.equals`. For a complete set of NiFi expression language, see this [doc](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html)